# How to prove that a function is 2-increasing (copula)

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, cumulative-distribution-function, copula, vine-copula

There are three conditions to prove that a function is a copula:

1. $C(u,0)=0=C(0,v)$ grounded.
2. $C(u,1)= u, C(1,v)= v$.
3. $C(u,v)$ 2-increasing function.

Here I am concerning in the last condition how to prove that a function is 2-increasing
as example $H(x,y)= (2x-1)(2y-1)$.

Is it correct if the second derivative of $H(x,y)$ is greater than zero then the $H(x,y)$ is 2-increasing?

Comment: what is $H(x,y)$?

Comment: It depends on which second derivative and on whether $H$ is differentiable everywhere on $[0,1]^2.$

Comment: H(x,y) is a bivariate function defined on [0,1] x [0,1]

Comment: It is a partial derivative ∂^2/∂x∂y @whuber

Comment: Not all functions are differentiable.  Indeed, many copulas are not differentiable.  Just apply the definition of 2-increasing in any particular case.

Comment: suppose we have Farlie-Gumbel-Morgenstern copula the second derivative

Comment: Dear @whubar, please tell me how to prove a differentiable function in a certain interval is  2-increasing? Moreover, if the second partial derivative of a function is non-negative, can we say the function is 2-increasing. If yes, please provide a reference.

Comment: To prove that the function $H(x,y)$ is 2-increasing you need to show that the volume $\text{vol}_H(B) \geq 0$. Here $B$ is the Cartesian product of some intervals such as $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. However, you need to be more specific about the intervals in your case.

Comment: See Nelsen's book on copulas.  You merely need to apply the definition, which works even when $H$ is not second differentiable: for all $a,b,c,d\in[0,1]$ with $a\le b$ and $c\le d,$ demonstrate that $C(b,d)-C(a,d)-C(b,c)+C(a,c)\ge 0.$ For your formula $H,$ that's easy to do. There is an obvious connection between this condition and $\partial^2 C/\partial u\partial v$ when $C$ is everywhere differentiable, but this is only *one* of the second derivatives of $C.$  The others are irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd condition is

3. For every $u_1,u_2,v_1,v_2 \in [0,1]$ such that $ u_1 \leq u_2 $ and $v_1 \leq v_2$ we have $C(u_1,v_1) \leq C(u_2, v_2)$

That means it is non-decreasing (which is less strict than increasing). We can rewrite this as

- $C(u+x,v+y) - C(u, v) \geq 0$ for every $u,v \in [0,1]$, $x \in [0,1-u]$ and $y \in [0,1-v]$

Or we can use two conditions

- $C(u+x,v) - C(u, v) \geq 0$ for every $u,v \in [0,1]$, and $x \in [0,1-u]$
- $C(u,v+y) - C(u, v) \geq 0$ for every $u,v \in [0,1]$, and $y \in [0,1-v]$

With those two conditions we can see that your example doesn't work. For example

$$\begin{array}{}
C(u,v+y) - C(u, v)& =& (2u-1)(2(v+y)-1) -(2u-1)(2(v)-1)\\
& = &(2u-1)y\end{array}$$

And that is negative for $u <0.5$ and $y>0$. So you do not have a non-decreasing function.

This shows that a positive second partial derivative $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u \partial v} C(u,v)$ is not a sufficient condition.

---

Whuber comments about the rectangle inequality

$$P[a \leq x\leq b, c \leq y \leq d] =  C(b,d)-C(a,d)-C(b,c)+C(a,c)\ge 0$$

This resembles a second derivative. In your example case this quantity is positive, but still your function is a decreasing function.

I guess that the reason for this discrepancy is in the boundary conditions in the 1st and 2nd conditions.

In the special case that the 1st and 2nd conditions are fulfilled, then the rectangle inequality can be used to show that the function is non-decreasing.